# Security error in ios 9 in ccAvenue payment gateway

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, ccavenue

I integrate ccAvenue paymeny gateway in my iOS app before release of iOS 9. Payment was successfully transfer to merchant account in iOS 8. When i test my app in iOS 9 payment is transfer to merchant account but display the security error.

I also change `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` library. Before change this library xcode throw error like

> libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o), building for iOS simulator, but linking in
>   object file built for OSX, for architecture x86_64 clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: i face the  same issues

Comment: @MAC113 now, i solve this problem.

Comment: So please tell me how to solve this issues. Thank you

Comment: First of all import new `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` library. and check your server side `responseHandler` file.

Comment: From where to import new  libcrypto.a and libssl.a ??

Comment: @DevangiDesai you can find on internet easily.

Answer (score 0):

Import the latest **libcrypto.a** and **libssl.a** to your project.

Run the project in your simulator, go to the activity path folder, and check whether the two binaries are actually being dropped there. If not then there is an error with your code, please share your code here for that.

**You can also try this manually first:**

- Run in iOS 8 simulator, and note in the activity path where the crypto an ssl libraries are dropped into.
- Change to iOS 9 simulator, go to the same path location (specific to ios 9 obviously).
- The two libraries must be missing.
- Copy and paste the two libraries here.
- Run the code.
- **Note: Do not perform any clean build, else it will get deleted again. Just simply press RUN**

Comment: Not able to solve problem. Can you please help me out. I can see both lib in framework folder. But somehow its still showing linker error

Comment: @DevangiDesai same like above problem?